# template meta-programming for a double multiplication

Tags: c++, templates, double, template-meta-programming, c++03

I'm trying to create a method  that given an integer input, makes some computations (just a multiplication and a division) returning a result as a `double`. This method should makes the computation at compile time.

I've tried different approaches like this:

```
template <int n> struct Try
{
    static const double result = 1.0 / (double)n * Try<1>::result;
};

template <> struct Try<1>
{
    static const double  result = 1.0;
};
```

But still no success, I get always compile time errors.

Edit: I'm not using `C++11`

Comment: Replace `const` by `constexpr`.

Comment: Thank you.. I forgot to write that I'm not using C++11 so that doesn't apply

Comment: maybe it's just enough to declare a static const double result = myexpression  :D   but the problem remains.. how can I return a double using template metaprogramming methods?

Comment: There are no "methods" in your code. In fact, there are no "methods" in C++ (only member functions, but there are still none of them in your code). You should really use C++11 for anything involving metaprogramming, it's much more suitable.

Comment: you're right.. pure pedantry btw ;)

Comment: Why have you '(double)n * Try<1>::result;' ? the multiplication does nothing because n * 1 == n, you can remove it

Comment: Yes I put 1.0 but I could have put every other number..

Answer (score 2):

Credit goes to @ForEveR, I just fixed a small error in his answer. Note that **nothing** guarantees that the computation actually happens at compile time. Nothing really guarantees there *is* compile time. Shamelessly copied answer below.

You cannot initialize variables of not integral type in class with `const`, you can do it only with `constexpr`. Since you cannot use C++11, you can try this

```
template <int n> struct Try;

template <> struct Try<1>
{
static const double  result;
};

template <> const double Try<1>::result = 1.0;

template<int n> struct Try
{
static const double result;
};

template<int n>
const double Try<n>::result = 1.0 / (double)n * Try<1>::result;
```

Comment: Hey n.m  , unfortunately problems also here: error: template header not allowed in member definition of explicitly specialized class

Comment: Very very strange.. maybe it depends on my GCC version

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you can use another constant to help you to calculate the result

Here a functional example.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int n> struct Try;

template<int n> struct Try
{
static const double result;
static const double _tmp;
};

template<int n>
const double Try<n>::_tmp = n*2; // another usefull operation because it's useless here
template<int n>
const double Try<n>::result = 1.0 / ((double)n * Try<n>::_tmp);


int main() {
        std::cout << Try<5>::result << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Hey Vink, thank you for your reply.. ahah about that comment.. anyway, it seems not working: (.rodata+0x0):-1: error: multiple definition of `Try<1>::result'

Comment: @user3770392 which compiler are you using? This should work, though I don't get the need for `tmp`, just moving initialization out of struct scope should be enough by itself.

Comment: I'm using g++ 4.7.2 20130108 , I'm going to check again if it's everything ok.. Edit: just checked again, it should be allright but it isn't

Comment: It's weird that you get a compile error because i used a standard version of g++ that use gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Comment: yep.. I've also erased the _tmp variable but still getting the same error.. classic template problems ...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but it appears to me, that you want a compile time evaluation of a fraction into a double float. This can be done with a very simple template function. This working example creates doubles in the .rodata section (tested with gcc 4.8.2 and clang 3.4):

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N, int M> inline const double& Frac() {
  static const double result = (double)N/M;
  return result;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << Frac<3, 4>() << std::endl;     // prints "0.75"
}
```